# How to increase dev/fuse size to 5G, curenty having 1.2G

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount

I want to increase the size of /dev/fuse.I have used below command but giving me permission error.

```
sudo mount -o remount,size=5G /dev/fuse
sudo mount -o remount,size=5G /mnt/

bin/sh: 1: /dev/fuse: Permission denied
```

I had run below commands but no luck.

```
chmod a+x /dev/fuse
chmod a+r /dev/fuse
```

[image]